# Getting the region from geocode maps API

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the region name from geocode api google maps.

I'm able to get the longitude and lattitude with the following code :

```
$address ="London";

$coordinates = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=API_KEY_HERE&address=' . urlencode($address) . '&sensor=true');
$coordinates = json_decode($coordinates);


$latitude = $coordinates->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$longitude = $coordinates->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

the information i get back from google api is

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "London",
               "short_name" : "London",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "London",
               "short_name" : "London",
               "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Greater London",
               "short_name" : "Greater London",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "England",
               "short_name" : "England",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United Kingdom",
               "short_name" : "GB",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
```

I want to get the region (in this example) it's `England` what is the best way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm not sure you need `&sensor=true` in the file_get_contents.
That is for mobile devices and the built in GPS as far as I know.

To answer your question, you can decode to an array and use array_column to get to the 'types' '0' array and use arra_search to find where administrative level 1 is and use that in the echo statement to get 'England'.

```
$arr =json_decode($json, true);

$key = array_search("administrative_area_level_1", array_column(array_column($arr["results"][0]["address_components"], "types"),0));

echo $arr["results"][0]["address_components"][$key]["long_name"];
```

https://3v4l.org/gsnv4

Answer (score -1):

Check all `address_components` for presence of `administrative_area_level_1` type

Comment: I have no clue how lol. I'll have to look into it more! thanks though

Comment: You are telling that you can't find string in multidimensional array or what?

Comment: @JackDaniels they mean, simply loop over the data in `address_components`, until you find the one that has `administrative_area_level_1` in the entries for `types` …